# Creating form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code below,

```
          var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
          mapForm.target = "_blank";    
          mapForm.method = "POST";
          mapForm.action = "delete";

          // Create an input
          var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
          mapInput.type = "hidden";
          mapInput.name = "uploaded";
          mapInput.value = file.name;

          // Add the input to the form
          mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);

          // Add the form to dom
          document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

          // Just submit
          mapForm.submit();
```

it does work, but after submitting the value, it opens the action URL in a new window because i have given `mapForm.target = "_blank";` , is it possible to submit the form without opening any windows i mean it **should stay in the same window but it should not go to "delete page"**?, not by using ajax...

Comment: So, remove `mapForm.target = "_blank";`?

Comment: If you submit the form, the browser will redirect. You will need AJAX to submit it silently.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. You say you don't want to open a new window, but are using "_blank". Then you say "it possible to submit the form with opening any windows" which it already does since you use _blank?

Comment: ya i mean to say if i remove `mapForm.target = "_blank";` it does not open new window but it will open `delete` page on the same window , i dont want it to got to delete page at all...

Comment: Do you want the form to be submitted or not?

Comment: yes i want it to be submitted....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could send your data to an hidden iframe:

```
var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
mapForm.target = "myIframe";
mapForm.method = "POST";
mapForm.action = "delete";

//Create an iframe
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "response.php";
iframe.name = "myIframe";
iframe.style.width = '1px';
iframe.style.height = '1px';
iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
iframe.style.right = '0';
iframe.style.bottom = '0';
mapForm.appendChild(iframe);

// Create an input
var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
mapInput.type = "hidden";
mapInput.name = "uploaded";
mapInput.value = file.name;

// Add the input to the form
mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);

// Add the form to dom
document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

// Just submit
mapForm.submit();

// Remove mapForm 
document.body.removeChild(mapForm);
```

Comment: after submit call document.body.removeChild(mapForm); otherwise everytime it will create one extra form

Answer (score 0):

You can check the new FormData HTML5 feature. It's let you send a form by Ajax (a real form like it was a normal ) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

If u dare using JQuery u can use AJAX to trigger a request to the serverside, in this case i assumed delete.php, very easily.

In the head of your HTML file add the following line to include the latest JQuery API.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In your JS create your form straightforward, convert the DOM element to a JQuery object with the $ (JQuery) method and create a AJAXForm with the ajax() method of the newly created JQuery object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
      mapForm.method = "POST";
      mapForm.action = "delete.php";

      // Create an input
      var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
      mapInput.type = "hidden";
      mapInput.name = "uploaded";
      mapInput.value = file.name;

      // Add the input to the form
      mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);

      document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

      var frm = $(mapForm);
      frm.submit(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                  alert('ok');
              }
          });

          return false;
      });

</script>
```

This will prevent yoor FORM from triggering a redirect to another page and instead use an asynchronious request to a server script to handle the data and push a response, that you can process within the success function of the AJAXForm.